# How to route request with dynamic value in gloo ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, gloo

How do I route the request that contains some dynamic part. For example I'd like request

```
/v1/employees/{empid}/reports
```

to be be routed to:

```
/my/host/v1/employees/{empid}/reports
```

Here `{empid}` is dynamic (alphanumeric) and changes from request to request. `regex` looks like would help with matching the URL pattern but how do I pass that dynamic value to downstream?

Comment: Something like [gloo rewrite](https://docs.solo.io/gloo/1.0.0/gloo_routing/virtual_services/routes/routing_features/prefix_rewrite/) would work for you?

Comment: You could also check [Gloo Github site](https://github.com/solo-io/gloo/blob/5c3adaf92e4e1c079b98ad0ed73a069c4c720cbb/docs/content/reference/api/envoy/config/route/v3/route_components.proto.sk.md#routeaction) especially, `regexRewrite`